# Zend Framework - Zend Tool - Module error: I have error after I create module with Zend Tool

Tags: zend-framework, zend-tool

I'm new to the zend framework.

I created a zend project with zend tool, and its works.   I then tried creating a module, but when I try to access it with a browser, I get an error.

My steps:

1. `$ sudo zf create project mystore`
2. put **Zend library** inside library

**test**: http://localhost/mystore/public/  (**working**)

Add **module** store (**not working**)

3. `$ sudo zf create module store`
4. add to **application.ini** path to modules

   resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

   resources.modules = ""

test1: http://localhost/mystore/public/store/

test2: http://localhost/mystore/public/store/public/

test3: http://localhost/mystore/public/modules/store/public/

**test1+2+3 result:**

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (index.php)
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/mystore/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /var/www/mystore/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/mystore/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /var/www/mystore/public/index.php(25): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'module' => 'store',
  'controller' => 'index.php',
  'action' => 'index',
)
```

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to make this command that create index controller of my module.

```
$ sudo zf create controller index index-action-included=1 store
```

Answer (score 1):

Do other actions/controllers work on the standard install, the case before you added the module (at the URL http://localhost/mystore/public/)? It might be possible there is something wrong with the rewrite rules in your .htaccess file.

The Routing in Zend seems to think that when you access your module the controller is index.php.

Comment: Their are working before i add the module.
Also now the http://localhost/mystore/public/ works.